# How to use with Base64string PDF data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, pdf

I have base64 string of the pdf file(**Gmail PDF attachments**), i am getting the base64 encoded from the server directly,now i need to convert this base64 to image to display the pdf in next tab of the browser.

I'm using the below code,
  var pdfAsDataUri = "data:image/png;base64,"+file;
window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
* the new tab is open and is not displaying the pdf

1. Can you sugest me, how to convert pdf base64 encoded string to image[i'm getting base64 encoded string directly from server]

**Note:** Please find the below image, if i click on that green marked icon, the pdf should open in new tab.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFqvS.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try making an `Image` object. Then in the `src` put the base64.

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src="data:image/png;base64,"+file;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,BASE_64_STRING" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: <BASE_64_STRING> part should be replaced with base64 string value

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use iframe

```
<iframe id="framTest" height="100%" width="100%" />
$('#framTest').prop("src", your base64 string);
```